# Find the Interpreter and Development Components of a Custom-Built Python via CMake

Tags: python, cmake

I have built some earlier versions of Python (eg. 3.6) according to the [standard prescriptions](https://docs.python.org/3/using/unix.html#building-python) and installed them in a custom directory, say `/path/to/py3.6.15`.

I am trying to find the the `Interpreter` and `Development` components via CMake `find_package` (see the [docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPython3.html)), under Linux.

As an example suppose the following directory structure of the custom-built Python

```
py3.6.15
├─ bin
├─ include
│  └─ python3.6m
├─ lib
│  └─ python3.6
└─ share
```

where the `bin` folder contains the Python executables, `include/python3.6m` the header files, `lib` the shared libraries, `lib/python3.6` the standard Python library, and `share` the documentation.

The CMake command is

```
find_package(Python3 3.6 EXACT COMPONENTS Interpreter Development PATHS "/path/to/py3.6.15" NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
```

However, CMake fails to find the Python platform; the detailed error message (with `--debug-find` switch) is

```
Paths specified by the find_package HINTS option.

  none

Paths specified by the find_package PATHS option.

  /path/to/py3.6.15

find_package considered the following locations for the Config module:

  /path/to/py3.6.15/Python3Config.cmake
  /path/to/py3.6.15/python3-config.cmake
  /path/to/py3.6.15/lib/python3.6/Python3Config.cmake
  /path/to/py3.6.15/lib/python3.6/python3-config.cmake

The file was not found.
```

Setting the hint `Python3_ROOT_DIR` (as mentioned in the documentation) does not help. Adding a `Python3Config.cmake` module to `py3.6.15` folder, which specifies the artifacts does not help either (see the corresponding [docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPython3.html#artifacts-specification)); ie., the *same* error message is shown. An example of my `Python3Config.cmake`:

```
set(Python3_EXECUTABLE    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/bin/python3)
set(Python3_INCLUDE_DIRS  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/include/python3.6m)
set(Python3_LIBRARY_DIRS  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/lib)
set(Python3_LIBRARIES     ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/lib/libpython3.6m.so)
```

NOTE: I am using CMake v3.20.2 on Debian 11. The custom Python folder (`/path/to/py3.6.15`) is *not* added to the path due to obvious reasons.

I'd like to know if there is some proper solution to this problem, without hardcoding the paths of the custom Python binaries/libraries in the CMake scripts.

Comment: In `PATH` option specify **absolute path** of the directory, containing `Python3Config.cmake` file. You may use expression `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}` for refer to the current source directory (where `CMakeLists.txt` is located).

Comment: @Tsyvarev : I corrected my question to avoid misunderstanding. I always give the _absolute_ path to the Python platform.

Comment: So, does actual path to your `Python3Config.cmake` matches to one of paths listed in `--debug-find` output? Note, that for satisfy the version request (`3.6` in your case) you need also provide a script `Python3ConfigVersion.cmake` near the `Python3Config.cmake` one. About expected behavior of that script see [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#config-mode-version-selection).

Comment: The actual path to the `Python3Config.cmake` matches one of paths listed in `--debug-find` output. The second point is important; I have to check that too.